# Logging error to Oracle database from ASP.Net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog, error-logging

I want to log exceptions from **.Net Core Web API to Oracle database.**

I started using **NLog** but nothing is getting logged into the database. Also, there is error in the internalLogFile.

- The below version I'm using - ASP.Net Core - v3.1,
  NLog.Web.AspNetCore" - v4.14.0,
  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core - 2.19.80
- Also, in the NLog GitHub, it is written to use specific db clients and the below dbProvider is used -
  dbProvider="**Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess**"
  But I'm using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core instead of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, will this cause any issue ?
- Below is my NLog.config

  ```
       <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
       autoReload="true"
       throwExceptions="true"
       internalLogLevel="Error" internalLogFile="C:\InternalScopeWizardLogs\nlog.log">
       <extensions>
       <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
       </extensions>
        <targets>
       <!--Writing data into db--> 
       <target xsi:type="Database"
       name="dbTarget"
       connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=INSERT_HOST));User 
   Id=INSERT_USER_ID;Password= INSERT_PASSWORD"
       dbProvider="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess"
       commandText="INSERT INTO TSD_ERROR_LOGS (ERRMESSAGE,ERRLEVEL,ERREXCEPTION,ERRLOGGER) 
   VALUES 
       (:msg,:level,:exception,:logger)"
       commandType ="Text">
       <parameter name="msg" layout="${message}" />
      <parameter name="level" layout="${level}" />
       <parameter name="exception" layout="${exception}" />
       <parameter name="logger" layout="${logger}" />
       </target>
       </targets>
       <rules>
       <logger name="*" levels="Error,Warn,Fatal,Trace" writeTo="dbTarget" />  
       </rules>
       </nlog>
  ```

Comment: There is **no error in the internalLogFile**

Comment: Verify that Nlog.config is configured with `Copy if newer`. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting - Maybe start with getting a simple console- or file-target working first.

Comment: The NLog is logging into the file, but nothing getting written to the Oracle database.   Also, the Nlog.config is configured with the "Copy if Newer" setting

Comment: Any reason why you are using `levels="Error,Warn,Fatal,Trace"` instead of `minLevel="Debug"` ? (Currently excluding Info-Level + Debug-Level)

Comment: I used minLevel = Debug, earlier. So, i changed to Error, Warn explicitly to see if there is any error that is not catched with Debug

Comment: With this config minLevel = Debug, I'm able to debug information in the NLog config file. Also, I'm able to log information in the file with "Target = File"......Only it is not logging anything in Oracle db ,niether giving any error

Comment: Guess you have to change to `internalLogLevel="Trace"` and look for clues in the NLog InternalLogger-output to see what happens with database-target against the Oracle Db.